# componentDidMount not called on HashRouter Route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

First of all: **I know that this question has already been asked here and that there is also already a solution. Please read the whole post before marking this as a duplicate**

I am using the HashRouter from react-router-dom and I have this simple route:

```
<Route path='/folder/:folderId' component={FileArea} />
```

The routing works fine but unfortunately my `componentDidMount` function is not being called after a route change. This is crutial for my application to work as I have to make an API Call every time the route changes to retrieve the corresponding data (according to the folderId url parameter).

I found a solution in the internet using `componentWillReceiveProps` and this would work fine for me but apparently this function will no longer work in future react versions: [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

I also know that I could theoretically use `static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)` but this function is called way to often and it would be rediculous to make an api call each time.

Is there an alternative for `componentWillReceiveProps` or some way to invoke `componentDidMount`?

Comment: You can use `componentDidUpdate` to resolve

Comment: @RyanNghiem componentDidUpdate only contains prevProps and prevState but I need the next props

Comment: `next props` is this.props, `next state` is this.state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use componentDidUpdate() life cycle hooks.

and to get the route data in your component use `this.props.match.params.folderId` in that method

and to stop continuous call add `if` condition it will only call whenever route change.

I hope it will work!!

Comment: Thanks! The last part with the prevention of the continuouscall helped.